# set limit for the number of columns per row in a html table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

May I know what are the ways to limit the number of columns of a Html table (e.g. 3 columns per row)?

FYI, I'm using row.insertCell() to add cells to a particular row with matching the row id. I wish to limit the cell number to only 3 per row in the table.

Comment: just check before row.insetCell how many cells the table already have, if its equal 3, u dont insert cell.

Comment: Please add some code you have. Are you creating a new table, or rather adding new cells / rows to a table after a user action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such limit in the javascript or html standard. you have to enforce it yourself as a rule during the insertion.

A simple counter does the trick.

```
var items = ['c00', 'c01', 'c02', 'c10', 'c11', 'c12'];  //sample data

var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var row;

for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
  if(i % 3 == 0) {   //after every third cell add a new row and change the row variable to point to it
     row = table.insertRow(-1);      
  }
  var cell = row.insertCell(-1);  //simply insert the row
  cell.innerHTML = items[i];
}
```

there are a number of ways of doing it. it will really depend on how you structure your code.

Answer (score 1):

"Limit"? There's no natural limit. You'll have to enforce it yourself on your own code.

Check if the row you're inserting into already has 3 cells, and don't add a new one if it does.

Comment: I know there's no "limit" but I wish to set a limit for it
I wish to limit the cells in a row to 3 and create another new row after the limit is hit, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`row.cells`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement) collection to check, how many cells a row contains.

```
var row = document.getElementById('row_id'),
    cells = row.cells, max = 3;
if (cells.length < max) {
    // Add cell(s) to #row_id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
row.insertCell()
```